# Hardware virtualization?

Tags: virtualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enabling hardware virtualisation BIOS; anything to beware?](https://serverfault.com/questions/7690/enabling-hardware-virtualisation-bios-anything-to-beware)

I have an processor option in BIOS:
**"Hardware assised virtualization"**

It's turned off by default.

Do I get some benefits if I turn it on?, if so what benefits.
also for what is it used?

Comment: Please please please, read the [faq].

Comment: Is there anything in your question not addressed by [the Wikipedia article on Hardware Assisted Virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware-assisted_virtualization) or  [the Wikipedia article on x86 virtualization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Hardware_assist)?

Comment: -1 for a general lack of effort on this one, codekiddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qouted from wikipedia:

"hardware-assisted virtualization is a platform virtualization approach that enables efficient full virtualization using help from hardware capabilities, primarily from the host processors".

Hardware-assisted virtualization reduces the maintenance overhead of paravirtualization as it reduces (ideally, eliminates) the changes needed in the guest operating system.

Hardware-assisted virtualization requires explicit support in the host CPU, which is not available on all x86/x86_64 processors.

Plenty of articles on the net,  please do some basic research and please read FAQ.